# I don't know how to locate the position of the highest random number

Tags: c++

1.)  Write a program that generates ten random numbers in the range of 1 to 100.  Output the highest random number generated and its position in the list.
Sample Output:  The ten random numbers (1-100) generated are:
        5     23     12     6     8     90     1     5      56     89
        The highest number generated is 90, and it is number 6 on the list.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>   
#include <cstdlib>  
#include <ctime>   
#include <windows.h> 

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int rndNum, highest, position, ctr;
    char tryagain;

    do {
       system("cls");  
       cout<<"The ten random numbers generated by the computer : "<<endl; 

       srand(time(0));
       for(ctr=1, highest=0, position=0; ctr<=10; ctr++)
       {
            rndNum = rand() % 100 + 1;  

            rndNum = float(100*rand()/(RAND_MAX + 1.0));
            if (rndNum > highest)
                highest = rndNum;

            cout<<rndNum<<"\t";       
        }

        cout<<endl<<endl;
        cout<<"The highest number generated is "<<highest<<endl;
        cout<<"And it is number "<<position<<" on the list."<<endl;
        cout<<endl<<endl;

        cout<<"Press any key to try again and [X/x] to exit."<<endl;
        cin>>tryagain;

        tryagain = tolower(tryagain);

    } while(tryagain != 'x');

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to post the code that you've written for this so far.

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. Please [edit] your question and add the code that you have so far.

Comment: You need to update `position` as well as `highest` when you find a new maximum.

Comment: You never store `i+1` into `position`.

Comment: What should the line with `rndNum = float(100*rand()/(RAND_MAX + 1.0));` do? It's overwriting the previous one, and it boils down to `rndNum = 0;`. It's just wrong, use the previous one instead.

Answer (score -1):

First generate the array `a[]` of random numbers using a random number generator. Then declare two variables, `big`: for storing and comparing largest number and other `indexBig`: is for storing its index. Then loop through the array and check if `big` is greater than `a[i]`. If yes then assign `a[i]` to `big` and its index `i` to `indexBig`,and increment it with `one` to get the position from zero index. Do this check for every elements of array. At last, `big` will contain the largest number and `bigIndex` will contain the position  of largest number.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
int main()
{

    int a[10], big = 0, indexBig=1;
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
     a[i] = (rand()%100)+1; 
     std::cout<<a[i]<<" ";
     if(a[i]>big) 
     {
         big = a[i];
         indexBig = i+1;
     }
    }
    std::cout<<big<<" "<<indexBig;

}
```

Comment: Downvoters please mention the reason..That is politness

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but you provided code without a single line of explanation or in-code comments. That's frowned upon, because it will likely not help OP and neither somebody who finds this answer later on.

Comment: Code only answers without any further explanation aren't well appreciated (I didn't DV BTW).

Comment: Providing canned homework solutions is also frowned upon - better to help the OP fix their own code rather than just providing complete code with no explanation.

Comment: The logic is extremely simply. I thought a single reading would be enough. I have now added more explanation.